# Multi-Mobject FadeIn and FadeOut Simultaneously in manim

Tags: manim

I want to draw multiple Circles that appear and disappear almost simultaneously.
How should I write the code?

If the scene I want to draw is the scene like all the circles appear and then all the circles disappear, then, I could write it like case A in the code below, but that is not what I want to do.

How can I draw the scene where some circles appear after some disappear？
I tried Trial1 but it didn't show anything.

```
from manim import *

class MultiMobjectFadeInAndOut(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        circles = [Circle(r / 10) for r in range(10)]
        anims_in = [FadeIn(c, scale=10) for c in circles]
        anims_out = [FadeOut(c, scale=10) for c in circles]

        # Case A
        self.play(LaggedStart(*anims_in, lag_ratio=0.1))
        self.play(LaggedStart(*anims_out, lag_ratio=0.1))

        # Trial 1
        anims = []
        anims.extend(anims_in)
        anims.extend(anims_out)
        self.play(LaggedStart(*anims, lag_ratio=0.1))
```

I'm using Manim Community v0.16.0.post0

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. You want to use a combination of `Succession` for individual circles, and then combine them with `LaggedStart`:

```py
from manim import *


class MultiMobjectFadeInAndOut(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        circles = [
            Circle(r / 10).move_to(ORIGIN + 5 * LEFT + RIGHT * r) for r in range(10)
        ]
        anims = [Succession(FadeIn(c, scale=10), FadeOut(c, scale=10)) for c in circles]

        self.play(LaggedStart(*anims, lag_ratio=0.1))
```

(I added the `.move_to` to make it easier to see but you could take that part out)

[image: rendered gif of scene]